# post api with address field as foreign key should pass all attributes as city,area,

Tags: django, api, foreign-keys

post API for passing foreign key attribute value with many fields of the address field in signup.

```
    # Employee model
    class Employee(models.Model):
        address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        nationality = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
        profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/', max_length=225, null=True, blank=True)

    # Address model    
    class Address(models.Model):
        area = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        pincode = models.CharField(max_length=6)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.state


        @classmethod
        def create_employee(cls, email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile_number, dob, nationality, department,
                            skill):
            user = User.objects.create(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, username=email)
            if not password:
                password = User.objects.make_random_password()
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            dob_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dob, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            for id in department:
                department_to_add = Department.objects.get(id=int(id))

            emp = cls.objects.create(user=user, email=email, mobile_number=mobile_number, dob=dob_obj,
                                     nationality=nationality,
            return emp
```

while signup for address field expected: address value passed with city, area,Pincode

I want to pass address field value with it's attributes.

Comment: pls, help me someone.

Comment: I would but I don't know what your question is.

Comment: I want to pass values for the address field which is a foreign key of the employee model, so for all attributes of the address field how could I pass a value with post api

Comment: Don't know because you haven't given any details of your "api".

Comment: {
    "email": "pjqj@kk.com",
    "password": "password",
    "first_name": "first_name",
    "last_name": "last_name",
    "mobile_number": "+914293138467",
    "dob": "1997-12-12",
    "gender":"hhhh",
    "nationality": "Indian",
    "department":["2"],
    "skills":["1"],
    "address": {
        "area": "HBR Layout",
        "street": "HBR Layout",
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "state": "Karnataka",
        "pin_code": "560043"
    }
}

Comment: This is how I passing my post API,

Comment: So are you using django-rest-framework? If so it will do this for you.

Comment: what will do, for the address I need to create objects first then for the employee.